# How can I add multiple conditions to if statment in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a project in PHP. And in session.php I allow which users can access each page. Logged-in users and other. But the problem is that I can't add all the id-s from the table in my database to the if statement. Because I would like that all 'oglasi' should be accessible by all users.

```
        <?php
        include_once 'db.php';
        session_start();
        ob_start();

        $query = "SELECT id FROM oglasi";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        //if not logged in you can access
        if (empty($_SESSION['user_id']) &&
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/index.php' &&
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/registration.php' &&
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/oglasi.php' &&
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/oglasi_show.php?id='.$id &&
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/user_insert.php' &&
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/login_check.php') 
            header("Location: index.php");
            die();
        }
          }

        ?>
```

This is the key statement

```
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/oglasi_show.php?id='.$id &&
```

`$id` variable should change 1,2...
    But it is not changeing.

If I do this it works, but it is not good if you have a lot of data.

```
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/oglasi_show.php?id=2' &&
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/oglasi_show.php?id=1' &&
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Check with `strpos()`

Comment: in each loop create a string to compare like `$compare_with` and this variable is the string created in each loop dynamically. And at last compare this string with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.You can also make you `$compare_with` string each time using str_replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can simplify check this way:

```
include_once 'db.php';
session_start();
ob_start();

//if not logged in you can access
if (empty($_SESSION['user_id']) &&
    strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/SP/oglasi/') !== 0) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();    
}
```

Here you check - if  pattern `/SP/oglasi/` not exists in your `REQUEST_URI` at position 0 (which means `REQUEST_URI` starts with it) - then you redirect user to `index.php`.

If not **all** `oglasi` subsections can be visited by user - you can still use your condition:

```
include_once 'db.php';
session_start();
ob_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['user_id']) &&
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/index.php' &&
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/registration.php' &&
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/oglasi.php' &&
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/user_insert.php' &&
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/SP/oglasi/login_check.php' &&
    strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/SP/oglasi/oglasi_show.php') !== 0  
) { 
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
```